# how to remove a package install/build by makepkg

Tags: arch-linux, makepkg

Follow this [link](https://linuxhint.com/install_slack_arch_linux/), I build **Slack** in Arch by `makepkg -sri`. Unfortunately, it won't start and I decided to remove it.

Issue: When I use `pacman -Qm slack` it returns `error: package 'slack' was not found`, and `pacman -Rns slack` surely won't work as well.

How can I remove the package and its dependencies?

PS

`which slack` cmd returns `/usr/bin/slack`

Comment: Did you build _and install_ it? Is it possible that you got `/usr/bin/slack` from a different install procedure?

Comment: that could be an reason, I tried to restart my system and some how the slack works and I use yay to reinstall it again now I am able to start it and find the package via pacman as well

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
sudo pacman -R slack-electron
```

It worked for me.